# jQuery Add Code To Existing Objects Function Call Back

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a page I'm using the [jQuery Countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) plugin. The page currently has a function in the [finish.countdown event](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#events). The current code is:

```
$this.countdown(finalDate).on('update.countdown', function(event) {
      //set the actual time
      var format = '<span>%H<strong>'+t_hour+'%!H:'+t_plural+';</strong></span><span>%M<strong>'+t_min+'</strong></span><span>%S<strong>'+t_sec+'</strong></span>';

      //send the time to the countdown
      $(this).html(event.strftime(format));

 }).on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
      //countdown is done - add the ended class to container
      $(this).addClass('ended');

 });
```

I do not have access to the code that is generating this code - but I can add my own separate javascript to the page.

Is there a way to attach an additional function / line of code to the finish.countdown event?

I.e. if I wanted to do `console.log("Done");` when the timer is complete can / how do you attach that to the object - without modifying the original jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, you do not have access to the 'instance of the countdown' $this.countdown(finalDate)?  If you can get hold of that instance, you could bind another 'finish.countdown' event listener with a custom callback.

Comment: I mean - I can not just go in and change the current `.on('finish.countdown', function(event) { $(this).addClass('ended');})`

Comment: But I can put additional javascript on the page that will be rendered after the countdown instance is created. Not sure if that answers your question?

Comment: The $this is = $('[data-countdown]').each(function() $this.countdown(....)});

Comment: Not suggesting changing it, but assigning another handler to the 'finish.countdown' event (if you can grab the countdown object instance) where you can execute your custom callback function - not entirely sure if its possible given your scenario

Comment: Docs make it look like a finalDate (the date the countdown is to) is a required param so it would overwrite the original / conflict with the existing code. *I think*

Comment: The only idea I could think of is setting a timer that checks for any data-countdown objects that have the class "ended" and then do something. I would think this would be fairly browser heavy and clunky instead of just using the built in callback.